# Nested Layout not rendering properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an `application.html.erb`, that has this:

```
<!-- Truncated for Brevity -->
<body>
   <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
</body>
```

Then I have another layout `family_tree.html.erb`

That looks like this:

```
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>

<main id="view">

  <title>Timeline!</title>

  <%= render partial: "tree_header" %>

  <% content_for :content do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>

</main>
```

That partial `_tree_header.html.erb` looks like this:

```
<header class="profile-header">

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="profile-author">
      <h2 class="center author-name">Martha Doe <a class="author-description-btn" href=""><i class="icon-list-2"></i></a></h2>
      <h4 class="author-title">Aunt <i class="author-title-circ"></i><i class="author-title-circ"></i><i class="author-title-circ"></i></h4>
      <!-- <div class="author-description">
        <p>Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod.</p>
      </div> -->
    </div>

    <nav class="profile-nav center">
      <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "Timeline", timeline_path %></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Family Tree</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

This is how I want it to render (this is static HTML):

[image: Static HTML Layout]

But this is how it renders:

[image: Nested Layout Render]

Notice that even though I specified the `render partial: "tree_header"` before the `yield` statement within the `content_for` block, it still seems to be rendering after the yield within my `layouts/family_tree.html.erb`.

How do I solve this?

**Edit 1**

Using amihule's answer I have more or less solved it, but now I am seeing a space between the top and the `tree_header` partial. Could this `content_for` block be causing this space?

[image: Space in header]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: move `<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>` to the bottom of your sub-layout and include everything else in your `content_for` block.

```
<% content_for :content do %>
  <main id="view">
    <title>Timeline!</title>
    <%= render partial: "tree_header" %>
    <%= yield %>
  </main>
<% end %>
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

You want to fill up your content for `:content` first and then render the template to include this. The way you have your template set up, you will notice on the rails console that it renders `layouts/application` before your partial, like this:

```
Rendered test/foo.html.erb within layouts/family_tree
Rendered layouts/application.html.erb
Rendered test/_tree_header.html.erb
```

See [Using Nested Layouts](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).

Comment: Awesome. This almost fully solved it, I am now seeing a space in between the top of my application (`navbar`) and the `tree_header`. Could the `content_for` be causing this? I have updated the question with more details about what I am seeing and a screenshot.

Comment: That's hard to tell from just a screenshot, I suggest you compare the HTML output to your static HTML and look for a difference. In my constructed test, there was no additional whitespace or anything else between the partial and the content yielded.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

amiuhle's answer : put the `content_for :content do` at the top of your `family_tree.html.erb` file.

---

**Explanation**

Your code is executed in order. Let's see what happens

your_controller.rb

```
class YourController < ApplicationController

  def show
    ...
    render layout: "family_tree"
  end
```

The action will first call the `family_tree.html.erb` layout, whose first line is

```
<%= render template: "layouts/application" %>
```

So it will call the main application.html.erb directly

```
<!-- Truncated for Brevity -->
<body>
   <%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %>
</body>
```

At this point, there is no `content_for(:content)` defined, so it will simply yield the show as normal ! Then it resumes where it jumped from in `family_tree`

```
<main id="view">

  <title>Timeline!</title>

  <%= render partial: "tree_header" %>

  <!-- The below piece of code is absolutely useless as it is not used afterwards -->
  <% content_for :content do %>
    <%= yield %>
  <% end %>

</main>
```

As @amiuhle explained, this is because you set the content_for(:content) AFTER it is checked. The solution is to put the `content_for :content do` at the top of your `family_tree.html.erb` file.